# Python Sockets - Server with two client sockets connected, on two separate threads, overlapping recv data

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a server written in Python that starts a new thread with a new client socket for each client that connects.

```
s = socket.socket()  

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), server_port))  
s.listen(5)


while True:
    (clientsock, address) = s.accept()  

    # Instantiates a 'Client' object  
    user = client.client(clientsock, address)  

    # Set up client thread
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=do_client_operations , args=(user,))

    client_thread.start()
```

In each spawned thread, the server enters its own send/receive loop with the connected client socket, and processes messages from the client.

I've implemented a simple messaging protocol between the server and client, and a few automated messages to check whether that particular socket is still connected. When the client drops the connection, the server updates its 'list' of who is still connected accordingly.

That feature seems to work fine, but often times when clients send specific messages to the server, for example, Client 1 asks, 'tell me who is currently connected to the server', the server will send a response to Client 2 instead, as if `client2.recv()` is picking up the message before `client1.recv()`

Doing some research, it appears as if sockets are not thread safe, and that writing the program in this way was not a good design choice ( I started this project a long time ago when I was brand new to Python )

What I seem to not understand is why two separate sockets on two separate threads are 'receiving' from the same network buffer? Do multiple sockets created by the same process regardless of threads do this?

Unfortunately I've gone a little too far to where rewriting this logic would be a huge task. I'm thinking of maybe adding some addition to the messaging protocol, in which the client prepend's some unique ID to the message for the server to know where the message is coming from, and who to respond to.

But I have to imagine there is some easier way to do this.

Any thoughts?
( Also I hope this is clear enough, I don't post too much here )

**Update: More Code**

So here is the main loop that each new thread enters. The `user` parameter is the `Client` object created, which contains the client socket returned by `s.accept()` in the server's main loop.

```
def main_client_loop(user):

    # Do not let socket timeout, wait on messages from client
    user.socket_object.settimeout(None)
    client_msg_list = user.receive_msg()
    s_globals.message_handler(client_msg_list, user)
```

Here is the receiving function for the server

```
def receive_msg(self):
    logger.debug("In receive function")
    is_pickle = False

    # Receive initial data and extract message length
    data = self.socket_object.recv(s_globals.BUFFER)
    logger.debug("Received data: " + str(data.decode()))

    if len(data) is 0:
        logger.debug("Client terminated connection")
        self.is_connected = False
        s_globals.client_master_list.remove(self)
        quit()

    msg_list_out = []
    msg_list_in = data.decode().split('\0')
    for msg in msg_list_in:
        if len(msg) is 0:
            break
        else:
            # Otherwise add to outlist normally
            msg_list_out.append(msg[4:len(msg)])

    return msg_list_out
```

Relatively simple code, the client socket receives messages delimited by null bytes and puts them into a list that is given to a handler to process. This function is part of the `Client` object so it acts on `self`.

```
def message_handler(server_messages, caller):
    logger.debug("In message_handler with caller: " + str(caller))
    """
    :type server_message: str
    :type call: client_class_user.client_user
    """
    handler_table= {
        SERVER_USERLIST_REQUEST: partial(send_active_user_list, caller),
        CLIENT_HELLO: caller.poll_response_good
    }

    for msg in server_messages:
        try:
            exec_response = handler_table[msg]
            logger.debug("Executing function for msg: " + str(msg) + " - "+ str(exec_response))
            exec_response()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug("Exception raised when executing function for: " + str(msg) + str(e))
            do_nothing()
```

The above is part of the code that handles the incoming messages from the client. From some log data I've seen, which I will post when I can reproduce, the message handler enters the function with the `caller` parameter being a different socket than what was logged when the same object in the `caller` parameter called its own method `receive_msg()`.

This is where I'm currently stumped. Will update as I go along.

If anyone is still reading, here's a log printout of where the bug seems to be happening.

```
1545428257.7718635: Received data from: ('CLIENT_1_ADDRESS', 49807) on socket: <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('SERVER_ADDRESS', 6881), raddr=('CLIENT_1_ADDRESS', 49807)>
**************
0024server_userlist_request^@
1545428257.7718995: In message_handler with caller: ('CLIENT_1_ADDRESS', 49807)
1545428257.7719202: Executiing message for caller ('CLIENT_1_ADDRESS', 49807) @ <class_client_user.client_user object at 0x7f905a5c1ba8>
1545428257.7719324: Executing function for msg: server_userlist_request - functools.partial(<function send_active_user_list at 0x7f905af79378>, <class_client_user.client_user object at 0x7f905a5c1ba8>)
1545428257.7719395: Sending user list in pickled format to caller: ('CLIENT_1_ADDRESS', 49807)
1545428257.7719553: in send_msg with ('CLIENT_2_ADDRESS', 48266)
1545428257.7719624: Received bytes message to send: b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x0028263q\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x0027528q\x02e.'
1545428257.7719736: Sending data: b'p0033\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x0028263q\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x0027528q\x02e.\x00' to socket ('CLIENT_2_ADDRESS', 48266)
1545428258.1330225: in main_client_loop
1545428258.1330776: In receive function with ('CLIENT_2_ADDRESS', 48266)
1545428260.775301: in main_client_loop
1545428260.7753537: In receive function with ('CLIENT_1_ADDRESS', 49807)
```

Client socket 1 picks up Client 1's request for the userlist, delivers the message to the handler with the message and Client socket 1 as arguments. Message handler executes the send user list function with the Client 1 socket.

That function basically takes the current list, pickles it and calls the passed socket object's `send_msg()` method.

As soon as `send_msg()` is called though, the log indicates that it is actually Client Socket 2, that is going to send the message (with the user list). So Client 1 asks for the list, and Client 2 receives it.

That eureka moment hasn't hit me yet, I am struggling to understand why Client Socket 2 suddenly takes control over the message received and methods called by Client Socket 1, as these two sockets exist on different threads.

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

```
def send_active_user_list(user):
    """
    :type user: class_client_user.client_user
    """
    logger.debug("Sending user list in pickled format to caller: " + str(user.ip_address))
    uid_list = []
    for user in client_master_list:
        if user.uid not in client_master_list:
            uid_list.append(user.uid)

    user.send_msg(pickle.dumps(uid_list))
```

I cannot believe I didn't see this. For some ridiculous ( probably lazy ) reason, I decided to use the same variable `user` in my iterations in the `client_master_list` ( which holds all the logged in users ) as my iterating variable, which ultimately modified the user parameter I originally passed, so `send_msg()` is called on the `user` object which was last iterated in the list.

This explains why the first log statement writes correctly the original parameter, but `send_msg()` is executed on the last user to log into the server.

This wasn't even an issue with threading, just of carelessness.

This can be closed by whoever

Comment: sounds like you have a bug somewhere; sockets, on their own, should be fine used this way…  try and cut your code down and most a minimal working example that reproduces this, often while doing this you'll discover your bug, if not update the question with the code and we might be able to help more

Comment: @SamMason Thank you! I was about to go crazy thinking that sockets on separate threads _aren't_ actually separate. I'll definitely investigate this further given that reassurance, although I'll also add some more code to the post to see if it helps anyone help me.. hah

Comment: multithreaded code is easy to get wrong, a useful search term is "shared mutable state".  you need to be careful when doing it, but it's certainly possible

Comment: Much appreciated, will definitely investigate this!